# SQL round trip network latency

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, networking, ping, latency

If I'm making a call to my SQL Server 2008 database from a C# client how does the basic network latency contribute to the round trip to the database?  I guess what I'm after is how many round trips are required to actually get the data given that there must be round trips that are related to opening/closing the connection, maybe data integrity checks etc.

For instance, if I ping my database server and get

Reply from XXX.XXX.XX.XX: bytes=32 time=100ms TTL=121

What can I expect my total round trip time to be?  Let's assume for argument's sake that my query is `SELECT 1234` and that I'm running the same query 100 times using the same connection.  I'm only interested in the contribution of the network latency and not of the query performance - hence the simple query.

So, in summary, assuming a latency of 100ms, what's the cost in terms of latency alone

1. Of opening and maintaining the connection
2. Per call once the connection is open
3. Closing the connection

Comment: The question you're asking is not going to give the answer you're after, and depending on the documentation available might even be an implementation detail. What is your actual question? Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Put another way, I can either make a single database call which returns 100 rows or I can make 100 individual calls to the database.  What is the latency cost for each scenario (assuming 100ms ping time).    If my database sever is 2000 miles away from my client, 100 individual calls will have a significant impact on performance whereas a single call returning 100 rows will be much more efficient.  The question is, how does the latency relate to the total round trip time?  When executing a single query my guess would be that there must be more than one round trip made to the database.

Comment: You need to take into consideration ADO.NET connection pooling. The connection is not effectively closed when you close it. It stays alive in the connection pool and reused when needed. So, the latency is bigger in the second case because the client needs to send the query command to the server 100 times. But the connection won't undergo the handshake and authentication phase again. Anyway, no clear answer here as it depends on the protocol implementation.

Comment: I care less about the connection overhead than I do about the basic query round trip time 9and the added latency as a probable multiple of the ping time)

Comment: It sounds like @marceln hit it for you--the connection management is effectively nil, but you are going to have much more total i/o over the pipe if you send that same query 100 times.  Not to mention each time it's send there is overhead at several levels--not just the network protocol level but the ADO level, which well return a full recordset with all of it's overhead 100 times--that same recordset with 100 records .is only returning the recordset object (and it's overhead) once.

Comment: In any case, if you're trying to optimize something this is clearly not the way to do it. Usually you look into the execution time on the server and try to minimize that.

Comment: @jimo3 - you say that there is extra overhead at several levels and that's exactly what I'm after.  What's the overhead?  Excluding connections, how many round trips to the server are we actually making for a single sql query "round trip".

Comment: What I was referring to by 'several levels' was the OSI levels...i.e., each call is going up and down the OSI stack and like any supply chain--each middleman takes his cut.   What I can't answer though is how much "back and forth" there may be with what you would consider a 'single' call.  This might be possible by putting a Trace on the sql box...in the old ODBC days one would set a trace file and you could see that just dbl-clicking on a linked table in, say, MS Access, would generate quite a bit of chatter between the app and the DB before the 'single' operation was realized.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for